# Load plotly modebar with preselected value (e.g. boxSelect) in dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm creating a plotly graph in `dash` and am trying to create the modebar with the preselected action-value of `boxSelect`. When the graph loads, there is no preselected value in the modebar.

Here's my code:

```
dcc.Graph(
  id='scatter',
  className="chart-graph",
  config={
    "modeBarButtonsToRemove": ['toImage', 'zoom2d', 'zoomIn', 'zoomOut','autoScale2d','toggleSpikelines','hoverCompareCartesian', 'hoverClosestCartesian'],
    # This is the line of code I'm hoping initializes things, but it does not work...
    "select2d": True,
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! When configuring the `layout`, add the following arguments:

```
layout = go.Layout(
  # ...
  clickmode='event+select',
  dragmode = 'lasso',
)
```

[Reference documentation](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-dragmode).